# Facebook graph API iOS : How to get width and height of a feed picture?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

and I got result like these:

"===========================================

"id": "619421723284_367295343463689",

"from": {

"name": "ChED Ying",

"id": "619421784"
},

"story": "Chanered McDonald's Singapore's photo.",

"picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/542908_38595311133451268_195dfdd7739613_s.jpg",

"link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=385953111451268&set=a.161567683889813.28585.157162220997026&type=1",

"name": "Wall Photos",

"=========================================

> I know how to get large version of a feed picture element by replacing
>   _s.jpg  to _n.jpg but picture's size no idea

.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the width and height of the image like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/542908_38595311133451268_195dfdd7739613_s.jpg"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%f, %f", image.width, image.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with this API, I tried all possible fields ;-(

1. From Php you can load some bytes of the image (HTTP Range header) and read the JPG header
2. You can re-query Facebook, to get the photo object itself from this ID (I am using FQL API, with attachement field)

It's very annoying ;-(